# Tkinter button "clickbox" detached from widget in fullscreen

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am on MacOS 10.15.7 and have just found that when I run my application, the buttons work perfectly fine no matter how large I make the window. However, when I make the window go into fullscreen mode, the buttons register clicks inside a box about 20 pixels below where the widget shows. Has anyone else come across this issue? I'm using the grid geometry manager, with `sticky="we"` so I don't think that the way I've added the buttons is the problem. I have also called `grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)` on every row of my application to perform the appropriate vertical alignment when stretching.

Here is a small snippet that shows how I've structured the application.

```py
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for frame in (Dashboard, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
            f = frame(container, self)
            self.frames[frame] = f
            f.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nswe")
        self.switch_page(Dashboard)

    def switch_page(self, frame):
        f = self.frames[frame]
        f.tkraise()

class Dashboard(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One",
            command=lambda: controller.switch_page(PageOne))
        button1.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="we")

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
            command=lambda: controller.switch_page(PageTwo))
        button2.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="we")

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Three",
            command=lambda: controllerswitch_page(PageThree))
        button3.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="we")

        ttk.Label(self).grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=3)
        ttk.Label(self).grid(column=2, row=0, rowspan=3)

class PageOne(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        
        ttk.Button(self, text="Back to home",
            command=lambda: controller.switch_page(Dashboard)
            ).pack()

class PageTwo(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        
        ttk.Button(self, text="Back to home",
            command=lambda: controller.switch_page(Dashboard)
            ).pack()

class PageThree(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        
        ttk.Button(self, text="Back to home",
            command=lambda: controller.switch_page(Dashboard)
            ).pack()
```

Also, I realized that I commented out the calls to `grid.row_configure` so I don't believe that is contributing to the issue. Again, the problem is not happening with the application in general, only when I click the fullscreen button on the window itself.

Comment: Please show us a minimal example.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I've updated the question to include an example of my application's structure